# Render "Transaction Forms PDF Layouts" in NetSuite - Missing logo and 2 other fields

Tags: javascript, oracle, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have user event script which loads button on invoice which calls clients script and direct it to suitelet. I am able to print the PDF using advance PDF template but I am missing Logo and 2 other fields.

Suitelet:

```
define(['N/render', 'N/record', 'N/xml'], function(render, record, xml) {
      function onRequest(context) {
      
          var response = context.response;

           if (context.request.method == 'GET'){

          var ifid = context.request.parameters.custparam_ifid;
          var pdfFileName = "Invoice";
          var renderer = render.create(ifid);
          renderer.setTemplateByScriptId("CUSTTMPL_129_423403_SB5_175");
          renderer.addRecord( 'record' , record.load({
              type: record.Type.INVOICE,
              id: ifid
           })
          );
          
          //context.response.setHeader({
          //  name: 'content-disposition',
          //  value: 'inline; filename="' + pdfFileName + '_' + ifid + '.pdf"'
          //});
          //context.response.writeFile(renderer.renderAsPdf());
          
        }
        //Obj.save()
       // renderer.renderPdfToResponse();
        var newfile=renderer.renderAsPdf();

        context.response.writeFile(newfile, true);
           }
      
           return {
              onRequest: onRequest
          };
      });
```

PDF Using Suitelet:
[image]

PDF using regular NetSuite Print button on invoice:
[image]

freemaker code for logo:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" 
"report-1.1.dtd">
<pdf> 
<head>
<#if .locale == "ru_RU">
    <link name="verdana" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.verdana}" src-bold="${nsfont.verdana_bold}" bytes="2" />
</#if>
<macrolist>
    <macro id="nlheader">
        <table class="header" style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <#if subsidiary.logo?length != 0>
                        <img src="${subsidiary.logo@url}" style="float: left; margin: 7px" />
                    <#else>
                        <#if companyInformation.logoUrl?length != 0>
                            <img src="${companyInformation.logoUrl}"style="float: left; margin: 7px"/>
                        </#if>
                        </#if>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                        <span class="nameandaddress" colspan="9"><b>${record.shipaddress@label}</b></span>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                        <span class="nameandaddress" colspan="9">${record.shipaddress?replace("United States","")}</span>
                </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the subsidiary explicitly.

e.g.

```js
var invoiceRec = record.load({
   type: record.Type.INVOICE,
   id: ifid
});

renderer.addRecord({
   templateName: 'record' , 
   record: invoiceRec
});
       
renderer.addRecord({
   templateName: 'subsidiary' , 
   record: record.load({
      type:'subsidiary',
      id: invoiceRec.getValue({fieldId:'subsidiary'})
   });

});   
...
```